# Execute stored procedure based on condition to check if a cell value contains data or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL table(data) and it contains 3 columns.

| Id | Firstname | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 | Abc | Def |

I have to check the `Firstname` column value based on the `Id` column. If it doesn't contain any value I need insert values into the `Firstname` and `Lastname` columns.

I tried the code below:

```
Create procedure prodata
   @Id navarchar(50),
   @Firstname nvarchar(50),
   @Lastname nvarchar(50)
As
Begin
    Declare @name as nvarchar(50)
    Select @name = Firstname from data where Id = @Id

    If(@name is '')
    Begin 
        Update data set Firstname= @Firstname and Lastname=@Lastname 
        where Id=@Id
    End
End
```

```
Exec prodata '1','vijay','kumar'
```

It is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you want `If(@firstname IS NULL)`

Comment: Have you considered using a different name for your variable?  It's kinda confusing to have the stored procedure accept parameter `@Firstname` and then your declare `@firstname`.  Also, have you debugged this to determine what the value of `@firstname` is?

Comment: hi devlin, Yes. @firstname I am using to check what is the value

Comment: I would actually expect `DECLARE` for `@firstname` to fail, you can't 2 variables/parameters with the same name in the same scope. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j0u62Qjq) This is true even in a [Case Sensitive database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq5sx.png). Therefore, your procedure `sp_data` can't exist.

Comment: Also, as an FYI, the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: `NULL` and an empty string are different things. Which are you dealing with? Is an empty string qualify as having a value? (Hint: for formal relational DB purposes, it **does** qualify, but for application purposes it might not qualify).

Comment: FYI "cell" is a spreadsheet term, not a database term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below procedure. I think it will helpful for you.

```
    Create procedure prodata
        @Id nvarchar(50),
        @Firstname nvarchar(50),
        @Lastname nvarchar(50)
    As
    Begin
        Declare @name as nvarchar(50)

        Select @name = Firstname
        from data
        where Id = @Id

        If isnull(@name,'') = ''
        Begin 
            Update data set
                Firstname = @Firstname, Lastname = @Lastname
            where Id = @Id
        End
    End
```

Comment: A good answer provides an explanation in addition to code. And good layout makes a massive difference to being able to read and understand SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
If(@name is '')
```

To this:

```
If (coalesce(rtrim(@name), '') = '')
```